# Trying to custom train MobilenetV2 with 40x40px images - wrong results after training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tf-slim, mobilenet

I need to classify small images in 4 different categories, +1 "background" for false detection.

While training the loss quickly drop to 0.7, but stay there even after 800k steps. In the end, the frozen graph seems to classify most images with the background label.

I'm probably missing something, I'll detail the steps I used below, and any feedback is welcomed.
I'm new to tf-slim, so it can be an obvious mistake, maybe too little samples ? I'm not looking for top accuracy, just something working for prototyping.

**Source materials** can be found there : https://www.dropbox.com/s/k55xoygdzb2efag/TilesDataset.zip?dl=0

I used tensorflow-gpu 1.15.3 on windows 10.

---

- I created the dataset using :
  `python ./createTfRecords.py --tfrecord_filename=tilesV2_40 --dataset_dir=.\tilesV2\Tiles_40`
- I added a dataset provider in models-master\research\slim\datasets based on the flowers provider.
- I modified the mobilnet_v2.py in models-master\research\slim\nets\mobilenet, changed **num_classes=5** and **mobilenet.default_image_size = 40**
- I trained the net with : `python ./models-master/research/slim/train_image_classifier.py --model_name "mobilenet_v2" --learning_rate 0.045 --preprocessing_name "inception_v2" --label_smoothing 0.1 --moving_average_decay 0.9999 --batch_size 96 --learning_rate_decay_factor 0.98 --num_epochs_per_decay 2.5 --train_dir ./weight --dataset_name Tiles_40 --dataset_dir .\tilesV2\Tiles_40`
- When I try this `python .\models-master\research\slim\eval_image_classifier.py --alsologtostderr --checkpoint_path ./weight/model.ckpt-XXX --dataset_dir ./tilesV2/Tiles_40 --dataset_name Tiles_40 --dataset_split_name validation --model_name mobilenet_v2` I get `eval/Recall_5[1]eval/Accuracy[1]`
- I then export the graph with `python .\models-master\research\slim\export_inference_graph.py --alsologtostderr --model_name mobilenet_v2 --image_size 40 --output_file .\export\output.pb --dataset_name Tiles_40`
- And freeze it with `freeze_graph --input_graph .\export\output.pb --input_checkpoint .\weight\model.ckpt-XXX --input_binary true --output_graph .\export\frozen.pb --output_node_names MobilenetV2/Predictions/Reshape_1`
- I then try the net with images from the dataset with `python .\label_image.py --graph .\export\frozen.pb --labels .\tilesV2\Tiles_40\labels.txt --image .\tilesV2\Tiles_40\photos\lac\1_1.png --input_layer input --output_layer MobilenetV2/Predictions/Reshape_1`. **This is where I get wrong classifications.**,
  like `0:background 0.92839915 2:lac 0.020171663 1:house 0.019106707 3:road 0.01677236 4:start 0.0155500565` for a "lac" image of the dataset

---

I tried changing the depth_multiplier, the learning rate, learning on a cpu, removing `--preprocessing_name "inception_v2"` from the learning command. I don't have any idea left...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your learning rate, maybe start from the usual choice of 3e-5.

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a try, I was using values from there https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet#v2


```moving_average_decay 0.9999``` is'nt that already very low ? (as in close to 1)

Comment: If you have the option of doing some regularization also, like dropout. I would suggest doing that also. And about the decays, keep them according to the original command only. First play around with learning rate. Also, I misunderstood that the factor was actually (1 - f).

Comment: If you can increase your image size, that would also be great. MobileNet takes 224x224 and your data has too low a size. Maybe trying increasing this also.

Comment: There was something wrong with the learning rate, it dropped to very low levels very fast (like 1e-30 after 10k steps). One problem out of the way, thanks.

I can't get higher res pictures as they are extracted from a 720x480 one. They are very distinct (see https://imgur.com/Ex2AFAD for examples). I was under the impression that with custom training I could use custom image size ? (I specified 40px in the model description, am I missing a step ?)

Comment: If you can't change the size, then, the model has to be attuned to your data.

Comment: Got it to work, I made a simpler dataset with 2 classes and a few images. The learning rate was Indeed too high and decaying too fast, batch size was probably too small... This article was usefull : https://www.google.com/url?q=https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjf_9qsxuDqAhVDz4UKHe0FBE4QFjABegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw1ev_Z_y-hP5mTwOKCt1sNz

Comment: Oh and changing the image size in mobilenetv2.py is enough to have a custom size image input